# JavaScript: script doesn't see global variable only in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have the following code:

mytemplate.html:

```
<script>
  const DEBUG = true;
</script>
<script type="module" src="mycoolscript.js"></script>
```

mycoolscript.js:

```
console.log(DEBUG);
```

Loading `mytemplate.html` works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in Safari 13.1.1 with a `Can't find variable: DEBUG` error.

Wrapping the `console.log()` call like so also fails:

```
window.onload = () => {
  console.log(DEBUG);
}
```

I would like to understand why.

Comment: Possibly related to `type="module"`

Comment: don't you need to import?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that safari 13.1.1 defines a scope for that script tag and because `const` [creates block scoped constants in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), the constant wont be available outside that script tag.

In that case using `var` instead of `const` should fix the issue.